# deserialize function ( byte array to uint32 )

Tags: c, arrays, deserialization

Whats the best way to write a deserialize function to convert a byte array into a 32 bit unsigned integer?

```
    typedef unsigned long  uint32;

    uint32 deserialize_uint32(unsigned char *buffer)
    {
        uint32 value = 0;

        value |= buffer[0] << 24;
        value |= buffer[1] << 16;
        value |= buffer[2] << 8;
        value |= buffer[3];
        return value;

    }

    unsigned char* deserialize_uint32B(unsigned char *buffer, uint32* value)
    {
        *value = 0;

        *value |= buffer[0] << 24;
        *value |= buffer[1] << 16;
        *value |= buffer[2] << 8;
        *value |= buffer[3];
        return buffer + 4;
    }
```

thanks! or if there's even a better way please let me know.. thanks !

Comment: Since it is just a byte array, it seems a simple `value = *(uint32*)buffer;` would work.

Comment: This seemingly clever code invokes *undefined behavior* if `buffer` doesn't point to a properly aligned address.

Comment: You should use `uint32_t` (from `stdint.h`) in case `unsigned long` isn't 32 bits; you should also add a compile-time assertion that `CHAR_BIT == 8`, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: Moreover, such a cast yields the wrong value if the data is not in the same endian as your host.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer your first variant over the second. Or you might exploit parallel processing by having four local variables that take the individual bytes shifted by the correct amount. Then, in the final line you `return b0shifted | b1shifted | b2shifted | b3shifted`.

Anyway, it all depends on your compiler. Your second variant contains more load/store operations, so the first variant has fewer abstract operations.

Concerning readability, understandability and clarity, your first variant is great. It also works on whatever weird platform you are using (endianess, alignment), provided that `CHAR_BIT == 8`.

Comment: It also works if `CHAR_BIT > 8`, as long as the precondition that the input `unsigned char` values are between 0 and 255 inclusive is maintained.

Answer (score 1):

Your first method may result in better code, because in the second one the compiler must assume that the pointers `data` and `value` can alias (though this may be mitigated if the compiler is able to inline the function where it is used).

If you have a C99 compiler, you may want to take advantange of `uint32_t`, `inline` and for the second variant, `restrict`.

Comment: what's the difference between using uint32_t and what I am using? Also, this code will be ported to another environment that uses TI MSP 430.

Comment: The advantage of `uint32_t` is just that it's part of the C standard, so you don't have to worry about defining it yourself for new platforms.

Answer (score 1):

One can make judicious use of casting to do this easily.  Just cast the char buffer to the type you want.

```
uint32 deserialize_uint32(unsigned char *buf)
{
    uint32 *x = (uint32*)buf;
    return *x;
}

unsigned char * deserialize_uint32B(unsigned char *buffer, uint32* value)
{
    *(uint32*)buffer = *value;
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behavior. The OP never said that `buf` was always aligned properly, so you must not assume this.

Comment: @RolandIllig This also invokes undefined behavior in all cases, even if `buf` meets alignment requirements for a `uint32_t` value as it *always* violates [strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).

Answer (score 1):

Implementation in leveldb looks like. [Link leveldb](https://github.com/google/leveldb/blob/068d5ee1a3ac40dabd00d211d5013af44be55bea/util/coding.h#L81-L89)

```
inline uint32_t DecodeFixed32(const char* ptr) {
  const uint8_t* const buffer = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(ptr);

  // Recent clang and gcc optimize this to a single mov / ldr instruction.
  return (static_cast<uint32_t>(buffer[0])) |
         (static_cast<uint32_t>(buffer[1]) << 8) |
         (static_cast<uint32_t>(buffer[2]) << 16) |
         (static_cast<uint32_t>(buffer[3]) << 24);
}
```

Comment: `static_cast<uint32_t>(buffer[0])` is C++, but this is a C question so a C-style `(uint32_t)` cast would be required.

Answer (score -1):

You can write:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>

uint32_t deserialize_uint32(unsigned char *buffer) {
    uint32_t res = *((uint32_t *) buffer);
    return ntohl(res);
}

unsigned char *serialize_uint32(unsigned char *buffer, uint32_t *value) {
    *((uint32_t *) buffer) = htonl(*value);
    return buffer;
}
```

This implementation ensures that the byte ordering is the correct independently from the underlying architecture.

Comment: That won't work in every case because the buffer might point to some address that is not properly aligned for an `int`.