# Convert hexa array (char*) into integer

Tags: c, int, endianness, binary-data

I need to convert bytes into an int (or uint8/16/32) in C.
Here is a explanation of my code :

```
char* out;
//init
//out=read_udp (from equipment)
for(int i=0; i<n; ++i)
  printf("out[%d]=%x ", i, out[i]);
```

Output:

> out[0]=0x00 out[1]=0xAA out[2]=0x44 out[3]=0x12 out[4]=0x2B out[5]=0x00 out[6]=0x7E out[7]=0x3B

The first four bytes are a header, followed by an ID and a value (two little-endian bytes each).  How can I get the ID and value?

## Failed attempts

I tried making pointers to the integers:

```
char* p_ID;
char* p_val;
//malloc
p_ID=&out[4];
p_val=&out[6];
printf("%d %d", p_ID, p_val);
```

I also tried changing the byte order with

```
p_ID[0]=out[1]; p_ID[1]=out[2];
```

I also tried sscanf and strol solutions but I get weird results.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding your question, but I have a feeling that you don't need to convert anything here...

Comment: Unless it's a different endiannes there is no need to convert anything, just cast the pointer to the right type and dereference or, do the same and use one of the built-in functions to reverse endiannes. Something like `*(int32_t *) &out[4];` and if it's not the correct value then probably it's the reverse endiannes.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi No, that's not the best advice. What if the array is not aligned?

Comment: @EugeneSh.i tried to add a phrase to my question so it is more clear, if not enough, tell me i will try to be more clear !

Comment: It'll be better if you can post a [mcve].

Comment: I recommend you print the integer you think you have made in hex. Perhaps the placement of the hex bytes will give you a clue. Also perhaps read up on big endian and little endian byte ordering.

Comment: What about using bit operators to combine the received bytes the right way. Something like: unsigned short value = (out[4] << 8)  |  (out[5]); Also check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145390/deserialize-function-byte-array-to-uint32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me provide an example which you're looking for.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdint.h>

 #define SWAP2BYTES(val) (((val>>8)&0x00FF)|((val<<8)&0xFF00))
 bool isLittleEndian() { // just to check host endian 
   uint32_t val = 1;
   uint8_t *c = (uint8_t*)&val;
   return (1 == (uint32_t)*c);
 }
 // if the same endian, then no need to swap, otherwise swap
 #define CHECKSWAP(val) (isLittleEndian()?val:SWAP2BYTES(val))
 int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   uint8_t out[8] = {0x00,0xAA,0x44,0x12,0x2B,0x00,0x7E,0x3B};
   uint16_t id, val;

   // to prevent from alignment issue, memcpy used insted of assignment
   memcpy((uint8_t*)&id, &out[4], sizeof(id));
   memcpy((uint8_t*)&val, &out[6], sizeof(val));

   id = CHECKSWAP(id);
   val = CHECKSWAP(val);

   printf("outdata = ");
   for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(out); i++)
     printf("0x%02x ", out[i]);
   printf("\n");
   printf("Header: 0x%02x 0x%02x 0x%02x 0x%02x.\n", out[0], out[1], out[2], out[3]);
   // just to make sure whether or not intended values are retrieved
   printf("ID: %d(0x%04x), Value: %d(0x%04x).\n", id, id, val, val);

   return 0;
 }
```

On my pc, the below is the output:

```
outdata = 0x00 0xaa 0x44 0x12 0x2b 0x00 0x7e 0x3b
Header: 0x00 0xaa 0x44 0x12.
ID: 43(0x002b), Value: 15230(0x3b7e).
```

Comment: Perfect ! Works fine and been able to adapt to my purpose ! I was missing the `memcpy` part !